# Rerender on prop object variable change

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

Problem here is: When i update a variable inside an Object thats inside a state Array the child components wont rerender even tho the prop and so the state did change.

What is the best way to update a variable inside the object and then trigger a rerender of your child component?

```
import TestComponent from './TestComponent'
import {useState} from "react";


function App() {

  const [data, setData] = useState([]);

  function change(){
      data.forEach(e=>{
          if(e.id === 1){
              e.name = 'SOME NEW NAME'
          }
      })
  }

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <TestComponent data={data} />
      <button onClick={() => setData([{id: 1, name: 'peter', surrname: 'jackson'},{id: 2, name: 'tim', surrname: 'sun'},{id: 3, name: 'matthew', surrname: 'thing'} ] )}>Set</button>
      <button onClick={() => change()}>click</button>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

```
import {useEffect, useState} from "react";


function TestComponent(props) {
    const [data, setData] = useState();

    useEffect(() => {
        setData(props.data);
    }, [props])

    return(
        <div>
            {data && data.map(e =>  (<div>{e.id} | {e.name} | {e.surrname}</div>))}
        </div>
          )
};

export default TestComponent;
```

New Change Function:

```
  function change(){
      let array = [...data];
      array.forEach((element, index) => {
          if(element.id === 2){
              const entrie = element;
              array.splice(index, 1);
              entrie.name = 'New Name'
              array.splice(index, 0, entrie)
              setData(array);
          }
      })
  }
```

Is this really the most efficient way to update the state in this specific scenario? It seems like this is not the most performant solution when it comes to Object Arrays that consists of hundrets of big objects.

Comment: You have to call `setData` to update the state. It accepts the new state value. And  you should create new objects/arrays instead of mutating them. Mutating `data` (or the objects it contains) won't notify React that something has changed. Have you read https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-state.html ?

Comment: Don't directly modify variables stored in state. Those should be immutable. Return new state instead.

Comment: Okay so i reworked my change function to copy the specific entrie and make a complete new setState

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is this really the most efficient way to update the state in this specific scenario? It seems like this is not the most performant solution when it comes to Object Arrays that consists of hundrets of big objects.

There is only one way to find out: benchmark it. However, there isn't really another way. For `useState` to work, the value that is passed to it must be different from the current value. Which in your case means to create a new array.

However, what is unnecessary in your implementation are the calls to `.splice` and that you are calling `setData` *in each iteration* of the loop (due to how React works that likely won't matter but it's still not correct). You only have to call `setData` once at the end with the new array value.

You are also still not actually creating a new object but mutating the existing one. This may or may not work depending on how the object is used. It's "safer" to create a new object.

Here is a more streamlined version:

```
  function change(){
      setData(data.map(
        element => element.id === 2 ? {...element, name: 'New Name'} : element
      ))
  }
```

`Array#map` returns a new array from the return value of the callback, which is called for every element. The callback creates a new object for the element(s) with ID `2` and reuses the existing objects in every other case.